# Access Linux Samba-Share from Snow Leopard

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, passwords, login, samba

I have a linux machine with a samba-share. Other windows machines can access that samba-share no problem. Now I have a new MacBook running Snow Leopard and I have no clue on how to access it. In finder it shows the linux-machine, but I have no idea how to access it. In some blog it said that this:

```
`smbclient -U <username> -L <hostname>`
```

can be used to list samba-shares. When I do it, I get

```
`session setup failed: NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE`
```

I am at a loss here. Any help on how to approach that problem would be appreciated. Can you provide some hints or point me to some good howto?

**EDIT** Ok, I am stupid. It was configuration error on the samba-server, I mixed up the passwords.

Comment: by all means post your own answer below, to explain the problem and any steps you took to solve it.  you can accept it after a couple of days.  it may seem like a silly mistake but this info may help someone else in the future.  thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @quack quixote I post my own answer here. The problem was that I simply forgot that you can have a Samba manages its users independently from the system, accounts with the same name can have different passwords. I set the passwords to be the same, and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use the command line. You can just browse to in the Finder (`Go` => `Connect to Server...`). If it doesn't show up in the browser for some reason then you can also type a URL of the form:

`smb://user@machine/share`

Answer (score 0):

When in finder hit `command+k` and type `smb://servername/share` into the box.

Comment: I tried this, the problem is, it doesn't recognize the password.